# How can I combine multiple csvs in R that have different number of columns?

Tags: r, merge

I have 40 csvs that each have ~130 columns but they differ in amount of columns a little. The important columns that I need are all have the same column names. How can I combine all of the CSVs in R?

I have tried (after defining csv_path):

```
my_files <- list.files(csv_path, pattern='.csv', full.names = TRUE) %>%   
  map_dfr( read_csv )
```

Here is the error I recieve:

```
Delimiter: ","
chr (38): key_BeginSpace.keys, key_BeginSpace.duration, Image1_Name, Img1_Category, Image2_Name, Img2_Category, Image1...
dbl (92): trialsPracticeBlock.thisRepN, trialsPracticeBlock.thisTrialN, trialsPracticeBlock.thisN, trialsPracticeBlock...
lgl  (2): notes, ...132

Error in `dplyr::bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..1$session` <double> and `..2$session` <character>.
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you read all the CSVs into dataframes (for example using lapply and read.csv on your list of paths), then `dplyr::bind_rows()` can merge a list based on common columns.

Comment: You can also find common columns with something like: `Reduce(intersect, lapply(list(iris, iris), names))` where `list(...)` should be a list of your data frames. As mentioned by @Brian, it is easiest if you read your data into a list since there is a lot of functionality in R for lists.

Comment: Thanks all, I updated my post with a little more information as I was still having troubles.

Comment: Looks like you have columns that `readr::read_csv` thinks are two different types, like number vs. character. You can change your call to `map_dfr(your_list, ~read_csv(.x, col_types = "c"))`, but then you'll have to change the column types after you're done with `readr::parse_guess`.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your response. I'm still getting this error message that remains the same. Any ideas?